# Is it possible to show 2 date pickers in iPad at the same time next to each other?

Tags: ipad, uipickerview, uidatepicker, simultaneous

My client wants some kind of booking application when user sets date from and to...
Designer came with sketches which allow user to picker dates at the same time. Two UIDatePicker are being presented to the user. I am new to iPad and all I know iPhone does not support it in standard way.

Is it possible to show 2 UIDatePickers at the same time in iPad?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible? A UIDatePicker is just a control; there isn't anything special about it. You can have two UIDatePickers just as you can have two buttons or two switches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi
i think it is possible but only by coding you have to set frame and give tag to each date picker so that you can identify that row is selected from which picker..